# What is an equivalent Portuguese expression for "to have eyes on the back of one's head"?

Tags: expressões, tradução

What is an equivalent Portuguese expression for "to have eyes on the back of one's head"? ([reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_eyes_in_the_back_of_one%27s_head))  The phrase is often used to express surprise that an action was observed by someone else.

Example: *How did you know it was me?  You must have eyes on the back of your head.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simpler expression in Portuguese:

> Ter um **olho na [nuca](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/nuca)**.

Although when literally translated this seems to mean *to have an eye in the nape/scruff* (related to the back part of the neck), the intended meaning is to have an eye in the back part of the skull.

[image: olho na nuca]

(Apologies for the creepy image) Here's a few references where this expression is used:

> [O olho na nuca](http://filmow.com/o-olho-na-nuca-t82929/)
>
> [A menina que tinha um olho na nuca](http://hojemacau.com.mo/2015/06/12/a-menina-que-tinha-um-olho-na-nuca/)
>
> [Pra desopilar: o que é ter um olho na nuca](http://blogdomaximus.com/2012/08/17/pra-desopilar-o-que-e-ter-um-olho-na-nuca/)

Comment: -1 creepy image